# Swift 4 Realm Swift object

Tags: swift, realm

I'm trying to use realmSwift in my application in Swift 4 but i have an error.

```
public class Test : Object {
    @objc dynamic var id: Int = 0
    @objc dynamic var long: Double? = 0

    convenience init(id: Int, long:Double?) {
        self.init()
        self.id = id
        self.long = long
    }

    override public class func primaryKey() -> String {
        return "id"
    }
}
```

Error for line with long variable.

Property cannot be marked @objc because its type cannot be represented in Objective-C

Thx for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the [docs](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#supported-types) clearly state, numeric types cannot simply be marked `Optional`, because `Optional` numeric types cannot be represented in Objective-C. You need to use `RealmOptional` to store `Optional` numeric types in Realm classes.

```
public class Test : Object {
    @objc dynamic var id: Int = 0
    let long = RealmOptional<Double>()
}
```

Comment: Your code worked only if i remove  `@objc dynamic` for long variable

Comment: @Joezzz right, that was incorrect, check my updated answer. `RealmOptional` properties should simply be declared immutable (becase `RealmOptional` is a reference type, so you can still change its value, but you shouldn't change its reference) and cannot be marked `@objc dynamic`.

Comment: Thx for fast help :)

Answer (score 0):

You have provided Int value to the double, so it's throw error. Use following code for double;

```
@objc dynamic var value: Double = 0.0
```

I hope this will fix your issue.

For more info: https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest#property-attributes

Comment: No, that's not the issue. The compiler can convert `Int` numeric literals to `Double` automatically, there's no need to write `0.0`.